# Android: Action Buttons Icons always appearing in overlay

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

My Action Bar Items are all appearing in overlay. Below is the code for my xml in res/menu folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search / will display always -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Location Found -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
          android:title="@string/action_location_found"
          android:showAsAction="always" />

    <!-- Refresh -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
          android:title="@string/action_refresh"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <!-- Help -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
          android:title="@string/action_help"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>

    <!-- Check updates -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
          android:title="@string/action_check_updates"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

In the main activity I am inflating menu via this lines of code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

While creating the project I selected none theme. Is this which is causing the problem? How can this problem be solved ?

The default theme which is selected is `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

Below is the attached screenshot
*[image: emphasized text]*

Comment: Can you add a screen-shoot of the final result ?

Comment: I have added the req screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on versions as low as Android 2.1, the showAsAction attribute is not available from the android: namespace. Instead this attribute is provided by the Support Library and you must define your own XML namespace and use that namespace as the attribute prefix. (A custom XML namespace should be based on your app name, but it can be any name you want and is only accessible within the scope of the file in which you declare it.) For example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

You are missing custom namespace in the main_activity_actions.xml. Remove yourapp with the name of app or anything.